Gradle build fails with "Could not find com.github.leyan95:android-zxingLibrary:0.1.2-PRE" in Flutter project using flutter_telpo plugin
I am developing a Flutter application that uses the flutter_telpo plugin, which in turn depends on android-zxingLibrary. I want to compile the Android build of my project successfully.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not find com.github.leyan95:android-zxingLibrary:0.1.2-PRE.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/leyan95/android-zxingLibrary/0.1.2-PRE/android-zxingLibrary-0.1.2-PRE.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/leyan95/android-zxingLibrary/0.1.2-PRE/android-zxingLibrary-0.1.2-PRE.pom
- https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/github/leyan95/android-zxingLibrary/0.1.2-PRE/android-zxingLibrary-0.1.2-PRE.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/leyan95/android-zxingLibrary/0.1.2-PRE/android-zxingLibrary-0.1.2-PRE.pom
Required by:
project :app > project :flutter_telpo


A brief search online for the error you mentioned yielded the following results:

https://github.com/wu9007/qrcode_scanner/issues/127
https://github.com/wu9007/qrcode_scanner/issues/91

If you go into the first link, you will see that an explanation and a solution is provided there.
Since the com.github.leyan95:android-zxingLibrary:0.1.2-PRE library was hosted on JCenter and due to the fact JCenter is shutting down, it means the owner of this library needs to migrate it to maven.
If that does not happen, you can either:

Take the code from the repository and host it yourself somewhere (or include it locally)
Find another library that enables the same behavior

Having said that, in the first link you can see that they provided a solution that states to put the following in your build.gradle file (at the end):
allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }

